# Import of XML nodes and removing namespace

Tags: php, xml, namespaces, domdocument

I have a XML feed of products that I break down into smaller XML files using `DOMDocument` and `DOMXpath` in PHP.

I create the new XML file, add a root node then import all the deep-copied nodes from the main feed. I want to remove the namespace from the imported node.

I have tried `$node->removeAttributeNS( 'myurl' , '' )` which correctly removes the `xmlns` attribute from the node but creates a default namespace so the output looks like

```
<default:node />
```

would like to remove any trace of namespaces associated with the imported node ready for registering new namespaces.

Any tips gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is actually what you are looking for but have you thought about using `xml_parser_create()` or `xml_parser_create_ns() to create a parser and then set your own processing functions to remove the namespaces.

```
$xmlParser = xml_parser_create();
xml_set_element_handler($xmlParser, "startElementHandler", "endElementHandler"); // start and end ElementHandlers are call backs to your handling functions that handle the beginning and ending of tags.
xml_set_default_handler($xmlParser, "handleMe"); // handleMe is a callback to your function to handle the data inside the tags.
xml_parse($xmlParser, $xmlData);
```

There are more functions that can be used to handle the xml found at php.net